# How to create a List of Appendices using the Appendices Environment?

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, appendix

For our dissertation, my school requires us to prepare a Table of Contents referring readers to a List of Appendices on a separate page.

I generated the appendices using the \begin{appendices} command and then created separate chapters within that environment (for individual chapters of the dissertation). However, this creates a list of appendices ***within*** the Table of Contents.

I would like the Table of Contents to simply refer readers to the page where the list of appendices can be found. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: As was the case with your earlier question, please do tell us which document class you employ and which packages you load.

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book} and 

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}